# One instance of a class for all other modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm struggling a little bit with the ES6 modules. So I have my main.js and import module1.js

```
// module1.js:
class module1{
    constructor(b){
        this.property = b;
    }

    setProperty(i){
        this.property = i;
    }
}

export {module1}


// main.js:
import {module1} from './module1.js';
Module1 = new module1(5);
```

Now I want to have exactly this instance of module1 in module2 (which property = 5). But how can I achieve this?

```
// module2.js:
class module2{
    constructor(b){
        this.property = b;
    }

    calculate(){
        console.log(4 * module1.property);  // Sure, that doesn't work..The output should be 20
    }
}

export {module2}
```

Comment: Make module1 export the instantiated module, and let module2 import that instance.

Comment: Export the instance from module1

Answer (score 0):

You can export directly an instance from `module1.js`:

```
// module1.js
export { module1: new module1(5) }
```